# How do I merge two lxml.objectify elements?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I am parsing some XML configuration to use the settings therein. I am not going to write out the XML again, so my interest here is only in extraction.

I have two lxml.objectify elements: On the one hand an element containing default global settings, on the other one containing instance-specific settings. Each element is similarly structured (e.g. root.global_settings.lights holds the same kind of settings as root.instance_settings.lights) but there can be intersections as well as set differences. The elements contain some children text nodes but also nodes containing other nodes.

What I want: A single element containing all settings from both elements. Instance-specific settings override global ones.

The best solution I currently have is looping over the instance children and overwriting/adding to the global ones (at all levels where there are text nodes). I was thinking maybe there would be something more like dict.update?

EDIT: Just to give an example

```
<global>
    <birthday>Unknown</birthday>
    <wishes>
        <cake>Chocolate</cake>
        <gift>Book</gift>
    </wishes>
</global>

<instance>
    <name>Mike</name>
    <birthday>06-06-1974</birthday>
    <wishes>
        <notes>Hates flowers</notes>
    </wishes>
<instance>
```

would yield the same as if I had run objectify.parse on

```
<global>
    <name>Mike</name>
    <birthday>06-06-1974</birthday>
    <wishes>
        <cake>Chocolate</cake>
        <gift>Book</gift>
        <notes>Hates flowers</notes>
    </wishes>
</global>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any 'native' lxml solutions. Objectify elements have traits from  both dictionaries (you can access their values like a dict) and lists (you can extend and append an element with other elements). Update, however, does not work at all and extend has severe limitations, including the lack of recursiveness.

So I put together this recursive function that updates one element using another. The specific context here is using user settings to override default settings, leaving defaults in place where there are no user settings.

In essence the function distinguishes between four kinds of nodes defined by two characteristics:

1) Is the node absent in the default settings? If so we can just copy over (append) the user one.

2) If the node *is* also found in the default settings, we need to make a further distinction: Is it a DataElement - i.e. a node with a direct data value, e.g. `<name>Mike</name>` - or more of a 'structural' node without a direct data value, e.g. `<wishes>...</wishes>` in the example above. In the first case we replace the default node (and value) with the user one. In the second, we need to go one level deeper and repeat the whole procedure.

```
def merge(user_el, default_el):
    '''Updating one lxml objectify elements with another'''
    for child in user_el.iterchildren():
        default_child = default_el.find(child.tag)
        if default_child is None:
            default_el.append(child)
            continue
        if isinstance(child, objectify.ObjectifiedDataElement):
            default_el.replace(default_child, child)
        elif isinstance(child, objectify.ObjectifiedElement):
            merge(child, default_child)
```

EDIT: Testing the above made me realise that if a structural user element that also existed in the defaults, e.g. as an empty node, had multiple child nodes with the same tag name, they would gradually replace each other's data child nodes. To avoid that I created a version that edits a copy of the default settings. That way we continue to check against the empty placeholder element rather than the element we're gradually filling.

```
new_xml = copy.deepcopy(DEFAULT_XML)
merge(user_xml, new_xml, DEFAULT_XML)

def merge(user_el, new_el, default_el):
   '''Updating one lxml objectify elements with another'''
   for child in user_el.iterchildren():
       new_child = new_el.find(child.tag)
       default_child = default_el.find(child.tag)
       if default_child is None:
           new_el.append(child)
           continue
       if isinstance(child, objectify.ObjectifiedDataElement):
           new_el.replace(new_child, child)
       elif isinstance(child, objectify.ObjectifiedElement):
           merge(child, new_child, default_child)
```